# auth0 get profile information backside

Tags: auth0

I'm trying to get user profile information from Auth0. It works in the frontend with the pipe Async

```
<pre *ngIf="auth.userProfile$ | async as profile">
<code>{{ profile | json }}</code>
</pre>
```

But in the backend If I want to read the nickname and do something with it. I'm lost.

```
constructor(public auth: AuthService)
ngOnInit() {
   if (this.auth.isAuthenticated$) {
    const result = this.auth.userProfile$;
   }
}
```

I know that my varibale "result" is an Observable.
But I'm new with this stuff of Observable. And I try to get the value.
If I use the debug console, I can see the value with this line :

```
this.auth.userProfile$.source.value.nickname
```

But If I wrote it in my code, I have this error: Typescript error: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable'

```
ngOnInit() {
   if (this.auth.isAuthenticated$) {
    const result = this.auth.userProfile$;
    console.log(this.auth.userProfile$.source.value.nickname); // error here

   }
}
```

So someone can help me with this ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You access data within an `observable` by subscribing to it (this is what the `async` pipe does under the hood).

Here's an example for how to subscribe to your observable:

```js
// import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
// tap is one of many rxjs operators
// operators allow you to perform operations on data within observables

this.auth.userProfile$.pipe(
  tap(profile => {
    console.log(profile);
  })
)
.subscribe(); // this is what allows you access the data within the observable
```

Observables: https://angular.io/guide/observables

RXJS Operators: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Comment: Honestly, that doesn't answer my question. You write the code available on Auth0. I have this code too. So I put it in my code. What I got in the console.log is an Observable. Like I said in my question. I know that's an Observable. I want to read the nickname... or the e-mail or other info from the profile and manipulate them.

Comment: Oh ok, you want to actually change those values within Auth0? I misunderstood the question. (i thought it was just about accessing/viewing within the observable)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution:

in the class I enter this code:

```
export class getInfo implements OnInit {
   private login_info: any;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.auth.getUser$().subscribe(val => {
        this.login_info = val;
        console.log('print info', val.nickname);
     });
  }
}

public useInfo(status: string) {
  console.log('print info', this.login_info.nickname);
}
```

So In the useInfo method, I can use the information that I grabbed from the user profile.